# Python code to create a database

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a database from .sql 
my code works once succeeding test doesnt.
im using python 3.4 and mysql 5.7 hosted on google cloud

```
import mysql.connector

SCHEMA_PATH = 'mysql_schema.sql'
mysql_conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='X',
    password='X',
    host='X')
mysql_cursor = mysql_conn.cursor()
with open(SCHEMA_PATH, 'rt') as f:
    schema = f.read()
    mysql_cursor.execute(schema,multi=True)
    mysql_conn.close()
```

This is my .sql

```
CREATE DATABASE `X`;

USE `X`;

CREATE TABLE `profile` (
      `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `birth_date` date,
      `first_name` varchar(30),
      `last_name` varchar(30),
      `phone_number1` varchar(30),
      `phone_number2` varchar(30),
      `address_id` int(11) REFERENCES `address`(`id`),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `address` (
      `id`    int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `line1` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
      `street` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
      `suburb` varchar(100)  DEFAULT '',
      `postcode` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
      `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
      `country` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Australia',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

quit
```

i manage to find a work around.
if i omit multi=True
    mysql_cursor.execute(schema,multi=True)
the program would have an error but if i put back multi=True and run the program again it would again work once.
so put a try except so it works everytime.

```
try:
    mysql_cursor.execute(schema)
except Exception:
    mysql_cursor.execute(schema,multi=True)
```

but i would still want to know whats causing this issue.

Comment: Can you post error you're getting as well?

Comment: thats the thing i dont get error.it would run like normal.